# What is the difference between memory mapped persisted files and binary serialized files?

Tags: binaryfiles, memory-mapped-files

I have a process that collects information all day and stores the data in a flat file database via binary serialization. I've heard about memory mapped files, and I wonder if I can make use of this. But I don't really understand the fundamental difference between the two. Are they essentially the same thing?

Comment: Yes, you can use memory-mapped files. What benefit do you try to gain from that, or what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am gathering data, and storing it in a binary-serialized struct. But I now want to store it in an interoperable way (some string format) and also to make it more flexible if I change the datastructure later. This will no doubt decrease performance and increase the storage space. So I was wondering if I could offset it a bit by using memory mapped files.

Comment: Binary serialization packages the data in a structure that allows it to be deserialized again using the *exact* same .NET types.   Not a feature of an MMF, you just get the raw binary data.  You get no help reading it back.  An MMF is only efficient when you repeatedly write to the same offset(s), it is not an improvement at all when you just keep appending data to a file.

Answer (score 3):

The two things are unrelated. There is no difference to be explained. Memory mapped files are about doing IO. Serialization is about the data format.

You can do IO through memory mappings or through IO functions.

You can use all kinds of data formats.

These things are independent.

Comment: Ok, I am more confused now. If this is true, and memory mapped functions are faster, why would anyone use IO functions? Also, I thought memory mapped functions wrote data exactly as they would appear in a process' memory. Doesn't that imply a specific serialization layout?